# Is the gravitational wave strain unique?

Tags: gravitational-waves

We know for a binary merger system the detected gravitational wave strain is dependent on the following parameters.

1. Chirp mass $$M=\frac{(m_1m_2)^{3/5}}{(m_1+m_2)^{1/5}}$$
2. symmetric mass ratio $$\eta=\frac{(m_1m_2)}{(m_1+m_2)^{2}}$$
3. effective inspiral spin parameter. $$ \chi_{eff}=\frac{m_1\textbf{a}_1+m_2\textbf{a}_2}{m_1+m_2}\textbf{L}$$

You can see that these three parameters are symmetric with respect to m1 and m2 and the only way you can have the same gravitational wave strain signal is by switching the places of the two black hole objects.

Now I want to know if this can be said for system with more than two objects?, is it any possible that two different system configurations can have the same detected strain signal.

I could not find any reference tackling 3 body merger problem and I am not sure if this is a legit question to ask, but is there any possibility  that the signals we have detected so far could have a different system configuration (in the case if my assumption is correct)?

But in any case this is not something new, in quantum mechanics you have degeneracy of the energy states for a simple analogy

Comment: I think it's certainly possible, but such systems would be much rarer than plain old binaries.  As doctors are taught, "when you hear hoofbeats, think horses, not zebras."

Comment: Note: The strain will in general on parameters beyond the chirp mass, symmetric mass-ratio, and \chi_eff, such as the rest of the spins. These three are just the dominant dependence.